# Three Dimensional Array Changing

Tags: php, arrays

I'm calling an three dimension array from an API, however after different calls to the API the data back is slightly different, sometimes the array keys change. For example the first array may relate to type one in one case, whereas in another case it relates to type two. It's laid out like this

```
Array
(
    [id] => 
    [stats] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [type] => 
                    [option] => 
                    [modifyDate] =>
```

As stated before sometimes it relates to different types, is there a way of getting an array based on what is inside of it, for example if the "type" in the first array equals type one then assign that to the variable Type1?

Perhaps in a better example, in scenario 1 it shows this:

```
Array
(
    [summonerId] => 39562006
    [playerStatSummaries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [playerStatSummaryType] => AramUnranked5x5
                    [wins] => 4
                    [modifyDate] => 1481110651000
                    [aggregatedStats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalChampionKills] => 48
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 2
                            [totalAssists] => 171
                        )

                )
```

whereas in scenario 2 it shows this

```
Array
(
    [summonerId] => 34951469
    [playerStatSummaries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [playerStatSummaryType] => CAP5x5
                    [wins] => 16
                    [modifyDate] => 1481117277000
                    [aggregatedStats] => Array
                        (
                            [totalChampionKills] => 325
                            [totalMinionKills] => 1996
                            [totalTurretsKilled] => 26
                            [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 1048
                            [totalAssists] => 298
                        )

                )
```

After some trial and error myself i think a foreloop will be good as it could iterate each array and output chosen keys from the array however i'm still unsure on how to do this, any suggestions?

Comment: ..and your question is?

Comment: [See how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Lots of `if`s and `isset`s.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708457/2943403
Unfortunately, I cannot give more detailed information without **small** relevant samples of the related input arrays and a desired output array.

```
// $new=array(...);
// $old=array(...);
foreach($new as $new_key=>$new_subarray){
    foreach(array_diff_key($old,range(0,$new_key)) as $old_subarray){  // no dupe loops
        // perform checks between $new_subarray and $old_subarray
    }
}
```